# Получение данных из промиса

Tags: javascript

Использую React-native, там есть такой инструмент как AsyncStorage (работает аналогично с LocalStorage), я пытаюсь получить данные из промиса.

Функция получения данных (видите ли, в реакте нельзя делать основную функцию ассинхронной, поэтому нужна отдельная):

```
async function findUser () { const userName = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Login"); return userName}
```

И вот как я пытаюсь получить данные в основной функции:

```
console.log(findUser())
```

К сожалению результат удручает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ содержится в промисе, но как же его достать для нормального использования?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
(async function() {
    console.log(await findUser());
})();
```

то есть получить можно так же через `await`, но при этом функция должна быть получается `async`. Для некоего обхода, делаем самовызывающиюуюся асинхронную анонимную функцию

Comment: а в консоли браузера и просто через `console.log(await findUser());` можно :)

Comment: @Grundy не знал. А ещё через `.then` можно, я что-то забыл, а ТС уже убежал)

Comment: @Grundy а почему консоль позволяет так делать?

Comment: вроде работает асинхронно.